# Program to display packages by their size in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, disk-space, package-management, packages

I managed to fill up my Ubuntu partition by installing large number of packages. When I was installing them, I was thinking about future, so there is a number of packages which I will not use for several months.

Now for my question: Is there a program which will help me find candidates for deletion? I'd like to see a list of packages sorted by amount of disk space they consume. Command line programs are good too, but good GUI is a plus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two answers:

**From the command line:**

Install the package `wajig`, and then run

```
wajig large
```

And you will get a list of the largest packages that are installed.

The online `man` page for it is annoyingly useless; the main documentation is located at http://www.togaware.com/wajig/

**Using a GUI**

Synaptic has this functionality built-in. Simply launch Synaptic, choose "all" in the left hand column and click the "size" column header to sort packages by installed size.

Both methods will give you exactly the same values. I just prefer using the command line as I typically install using `aptitude`, so I can call `aptitude purge` afterwards and be fairly confident every trace has been scrubbed away.

Answer (score 2):

in synaptic settings/preferences/columns and fonts then enable size column, then sort by size

Comment: Answer already given ;)